# Pig Installation error: ERROR pig.Main: ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, bigdata, apache-pig

[image]

ERROR pig.Main: ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
WARN pig.Main: There is no log file to write to.
ERROR pig.Main: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Above is the pig installation error I got. Any fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is mostly caused due to the 'Guava jar issue'.

1. Check 'Guava' jar version in Hadoop and Pig.

   ls $PIG_HOME/lib
   ls $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib
2. Delete Guava jar in Pig

   rm $PIG_HOME/lib/guava-19.0.jar
3. Copy Guava jar from Hadoop to Pig

   cp $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/guava-27.0-jre.jar $PIG_HOME/lib/

For more info follow this doc, but replace 'hive' with 'pig' everywhere [http://cis.csuohio.edu/~sschung/cis612/CIS612_Lab4_2_Hive_CommonInstallationProblems.pdf](http://cis.csuohio.edu/%7Esschung/cis612/CIS612_Lab4_2_Hive_CommonInstallationProblems.pdf)