# ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/python/google/common/collect/Lists

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm just getting started with Pig and I'm facing lots of issues with running my first program. Any help is much appreciated.

I've tried resolving using these:

[ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/WritableByteArrayComparable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029383/error-org-apache-pig-tools-grunt-grunt-error-2998-unhandled-internal-error-o)

and

[Pig Installation error: ERROR pig.Main: ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70491736/pig-installation-error-error-pig-main-error-2998-unhandled-internal-error)

but none of them seem to work. Can someone give a more detailed solution of what needs to be done.

Pig version: `0.17.0`

Stack Trace:

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/python/google/common/collect/Lists

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/python/google/common/collect/Lists
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRJobStats.getTaskReports(MRJobStats.java:533)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRJobStats.addMapReduceStatistics(MRJobStats.java:355)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil.addSuccessJobStats(MRPigStatsUtil.java:232)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil.accumulateStats(MRPigStatsUtil.java:164)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:379)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.launchPig(HExecutionEngine.java:290)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1475)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1460)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:1119)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:1082)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:995)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:782)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:383)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:81)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:630)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:175)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.python.google.common.collect.Lists
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 24 more
================================================================================
```

Comment: If you want a detailed solution, you need to provide a detailed description of your problem.  Start by showing us the complete stacktrace for >your< exception.  Use EDIT to add it to the question.  (Not a comment.  Not an "answer".  As text, not as an image.)

Comment: @StephenC. I've added the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in some versions of Pig.

It seems that it (MRJobStats.java) is using `org.python.google.common.collect.*` classes instead of `org.google.common.collect.*`, and the former are not on the classpath.

The bug was fixed in this commit:

- https://github.com/apache/pig/commit/6dd3ca4deb84edd9edd7765aa1d12f89a31b1283

in July 2017.  Unfortunately, that is after the pig 0.17.0 release that you are using; see https://github.com/apache/pig/blob/trunk/CHANGES.txt.

So you will most likely need to checkout and build pig for yourself.   There is a link to the build instructions in the README.txt file on Github: https://github.com/apache/pig

Comment: Looks like the pages to run and build pig do not exist. Can you re-check the links?

Comment: I think using 0.15.0 version is a safe option.

Comment: Hmmm.  Someone should raise an issue for the Pig developers to fix the link in their README.md and restore the build instructions.  (I don't want to sign up to do it, as I don't have a personal interest in using Pig.  How about you?)

Comment: Yeah I will do that.